# Wrapping Interval Notation for Take

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I'm trying to implement the solution to a math problem in Mathematica, but my code can't handle a particular boundary case.  I think that I could implement a function that would do what I want it to, but it would be kind of ugly.

Here is the problem:

[image: Here is the Math Problem (Mathematical Proofs, Chartrand, Polimeni, and Zhang)]

```
letters = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",
"m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

GetIndexInAlphabet[letter_String] := Position[letters, letter][[1, 1]];

GetIndexInAlphabet["a"] (* 1 *)

AofAlpha[letter_String] := Module[{startIndex, endIndex},
  startIndex = GetIndexInAlphabet[letter];
  endIndex = startIndex + 2;
  Take[letters, {startIndex, endIndex}]
];

AofAlpha["a"] (* {a, b, c} *)

AofAlpha["z"] (* {z, a, b} *)
```

Does anyone have a clean way to implement the wrapping behavior that the function should have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = Partition[letters, 3, 1, {1, 1}];

x[[1]]
```

> {"a", "b", "c"}

```
x[[26]]
```

> {"z", "a", "b"}

Generalization:

```
fun[letter_String, n_Integer] :=
 With[{cr = CharacterRange["a", "z"]},
  Partition[cr, n, 1, {1, 1}] [[ToCharacterCode[letter] - 96]] // Flatten] 

fun["y", 4]
```

> {"y", "z", "a", "b"}

Comment: Thank you!  I see that Partition is the way to go here.  Unfortunately, even Partition has kind of an ugly syntax having to define the {1,1} for the cyclic behavior, but sometimes that's the way it has to be.

Answer (score 4):

```
S = First /@ Partition[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 3, 3, 1]
(* {"a", "d", "g", "j", "m", "p", "s", "v", "y"} *)
```

It's minimal because:

```
3*Length@S
(* 27 *)
```

and any $S$ with less cardinality will have at most $3*8= 24$ characters in it's union, so it won't cover the full letter set.

Comment: Thank you as well @belisarius.  I appreciate the added explanation of why it is minimal.  Also, CharacterRange[] is very convenient for defining this set.